# Prove that the roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ form an arithmetic sequence iff $2a^3+27c=9ab$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics, arithmetic-progressions

> 1. Prove that if the roots of
>    $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ form an arithmetic sequence, then $2a^3 + 27c = 9ab$.
> 2. Prove that if $2a^3 + 27c = 9ab,$ then the roots of
>    $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ form an arithmetic sequence.

How should I solve this problem?

If the arithmetic sequence is of the form $(0,d,2d)$, then
$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=x(x-d)(x-2d)=x^3-3dx^2+2dx.$$
So $a=-3d$, $b=2d^2$, and $c=0$.  Clearly,
$$2a^3+27c=2(-3d)^3+27(0)=-54d^3$$
and
$$9ab=9(-3d)(2d^2)=-54d^3.$$
So the first problem is true in this case.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=roots+cubic+polynomial+arithmetic+sequence&oq=roots+cubic+polynomial+arithmetic+sequence&aqs=chrome..69i57.11456j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Hint: start by assuming the the roots are $s-d, s, s+d$, Then use Vieta's rule.

Comment: Read this before you post your next question: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803).

Comment: More here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775922/roots-of-a-cubic-expression-and-arithmetic-progression/775940#775940

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x):=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$.  Then,
$$g(x):=f\left(x-\frac{a}{3}\right)=x^3-\frac{a^2-3b}{3}x+\frac{2a^3-9ab+27c}{27}\,.$$
Note that the roots of $f(x)$ form an arithmetic progression if and only if the roots of $g(x)$ are of the form $-d$, $0$, $+d$ for some complex number $d$, which is equivalent to $$g(x)=(x+d)x(x-d)=x^3-d^2x\,.$$  That is, the roots of $f(x)$ form an arithmetic progression if and only if the constant term of $g(x)$ is $0$, which is the same as saying that $$2a^3-9ab+27c=0\,.$$

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than posting complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: Excellent use of the technique to start by forming a depressed cubic. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $l-t,l, l+t$ be the roots.

Then  $a=l−t+l+l+t=3l \dots\dots(1)$

$b=(l−t)l+l(l+t)+(l+t)(l−t)=3l^2−t^2 \ldots \dots(2)$

$c=(l−t)l(l+t)=l(l^2−t^2)\dots \dots(3$)

Substituting for  $t^2$  from (2) in (3),

$c=l^3−l(3l^2−b)=l^3−3l^3+lb=−2l^3+lb \dots \dots(4)$

Multiplying by 27 and putting $3l=a$

$27c=−2a^3+9ab$

i.e.  $2a^3–9ab+27c=0$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE!Try to give hints first rather than posting complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: @Adri Maji That's how I'd have answered it too. Probably should add that as all the steps are reversible, (didn't do any squaring etc) the theorem is proven (in both "directions")  (+1)

Comment: @MartinHansen Exactly.Thanks